# Convert Elasticsearch DSL Query to Sql

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

I'm converting a project developed with Codeigniter into pure php. However, the project developed with codeigniter used Elasticsearch and I haven't Elastichsearch experience. I need to convert the Elasticsearch dsl query that I have shared below into a sql query to use in pure php. I tried to write the sql query. But I couldn't understand what tables he was going to. Can you help with this?

`` `Here function in controller in codeigniter (old project)

```
   $elastic_blok_listesi = $this->elastic_model->plaka_takip_blok_ara($cari_id,$sayfa,$size);
    $elastic_blok_listesi = $elastic_blok_listesi['hits']['hits'];
```

` ``

`` `Here function in Elasticsearch Model in codeigniter (old project)

```
public function plaka_takip_blok_ara($cari_id=NULL, $page=0, $size=10, $all=NULL)
{

    if($all == TRUE){

        $json = 
            '{
                "size" : 4000,
        "sort" : [
            {"blok_no" : {"order" : "desc"}}
         ],
                "query": {
            "term": {
            "firma_id":"'.$cari_id.'"
            }
            }
            }'
        ;

    }else{

        $from = ($page-1)*$size;

        $json = 
            '{
                "from" : '.$from.', "size" : '.$size.',
        "sort" : [
            {"blok_no" : {"order" : "desc"}}
         ],
                "query": {
            "term": {
            "firma_id":"'.$cari_id.'"
            }
            }
            }'
        ;
    }

    $this->qParam['body'] = $json;
    return  $this->client->search($this->qParam);
}
```

` ``

`` `Here My sql in pure php (new project)

```
  $db->query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM ?
    WHERE firma_id='$cari_id'
    ORDER BY blok_no DESC
");
```

` ``

Comment: Why not just use ElasticSearch in the current PHP version? Presumably elastic was used for a reason? Is the data text intensive?

Comment: We just took over this project.  No one from the existing team has any Elasticsearch experience, and we've decided to make this code simpler for the future.  Therefore we want to use pure php and mysql alone.

Comment: You are mostly there, you just need to handle the pagination. `from` in ES is the same as `offset` and `size` is same as `limit` in sql. For table name, look at the client->search method. In ES, tables are represented by index and it will be passed as part of the url

Answer (score -4):

you should use elasticsearch  sql translate

[elasticsearch sql translate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html)

```
 POST /_sql/translate
 {

    "query":"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE firma_id=bar ORDER BY blok_no DESC"
 }
```